# How to make a redirection to a Jade/Pug file within a MongoDB callback?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redirect, pug

I would want to use the Express' function `redirect` outside the function `express().get` (or something equivalent), and within the MongoDB's function `connect`,  if an error is raised at the connection to the database.

This redirection's destination is a Jade/Pug file, that's why I'll have to use the Pug's function `render`.

**My question is :** how could I use `redirect`, for example, in order to do this ? Indeed, I have no object `res` because I don't use the function `express().get`.

Here is the code I wrote ; it must be fulfill but I don't know how.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongo_client = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
mongo_client.connect("mongodb://localhost:27016/my_db", (error, database) => {
        if(error) { // If an error has been raised while connecting to the database
            app.locals.error = error;
            app.render('db_error.jade', (error, rendered) => { // We generate the HTML code and pass it to a redirection
                // But how ???
                if(error) {
                    throw error;
                }
            });
            throw error;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

More importantly, you don't have a *request*, because this isn't in a route. Not only is there nothing to render your response to, nobody's asking for a response in the first place. This is all happening before anyone's web browser gets involved at all.

If you want to show a page when the database is down, you'll need to use [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) on all requests to see if the app is connected to Mongo and redirect to your error page as necessary.